# How do I access User Folders from Finder Sync Extension?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, findersync

I am developing a Cocoa application with Finder Extension to set overlay icons on the file.

As soon as the user clicks on a folder that i am monitoring, I get a call to
the method `- beginObservingDirectoryAtURL:`

So my code is:

```
- (void)beginObservingDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // The user is now seeing the container's contents.
    // If they see it in more than one view at a time, we're only told once.
    NSLog(@"Current Path : %@", url.path);
    NSArray<NSString*>* children = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subPathsAtPath:url.Path];
}
```

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subPathsAtPath:…]` returns `nil` when called from the Finder extension.

The same method call with the same path returns the elements in the main app.

Can I somehow enable monitoring a specific folder from Finder Extension?

Comment: What is `nil`? `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` or `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subPathsAtPath:…]`?

Comment: subPathsAtPath are returned as nil.

Comment: And what is the result of `[NSFileManager defaultManager]`? `-subPathsAtPath:` can return `nil` for an insufficient argument.